# How to get data without getting "could not initialize proxy - no Session" exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a method to retrieve data from DB:

```
public static List<ClassA> getAll() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ClassA.class);
        List result = criteria.list();
        tx.commit();
        return result;
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        transactionRollBack(tx);
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<ClassA> results = getAll();
for (ClassA result : results) {
    System.out.println(result); //"could not initialize proxy - no Session" is thrown here
}
```

If I correctly understood Hibernate documentation, this occurs because session was closed. But how can I get data and close session (because it needs to be closed before next transaction that is about to begin in a minute)?

**Updated**

Here is ClassA content including `toString()`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classA")
public class ClassA implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5163856045361200311L;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private Set<ClassB> classB = new HashSet<ClassB>(0);

    public ClassA() {}
    public ClassA(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ClassA(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ClassA(ClassA classA) {
        this.id = classA.getId();
        this.name = classA.getName();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "classA_id")
    public Set<ClassB> getClassB() {
        return classB;
    }

    public void setClassB(Set<ClassB> classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassA{ id=" + id + ", name='" + name + ", classB =" + classB + '}';
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem is with `ClassB`, but I cannot understand what it is. Here is `ClassB`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classB")
public class ClassB implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8481028941663340911L;
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private ClassA classA_id;
    private int classA_counter;

    public ClassB() {}

    public ClassB(ClassB rec) {
        this.id = rec.getId();
        this.date = rec.getDate();
        this.classA_id = rec.getClassA_id();
        this.classA_counter = rec.classA_counter();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Temporal(DATE)
    @Column(name = "date")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classA_id", nullable = false)
    public ClassA getCLassA_id() {
        return classA_id;
    }

    public void setClassA_id(ClassA classA_id) {
        this.classA_id = classA_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "classA_counter", columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    public int getClassA_counter() {
        return classA_counter;
    }

    public void setClassA_counter(int classA_counter) {
        this.classA_counter = classA_counter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassB { id=" + id + ", date=" + date + ", classA_id=" + classA_id.getName() + ", classA_counter=" + classA_counter +'}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the toString() method, which is implicitely called by

```
System.out.println(result);
```

tries to access associations of the ClassA entity that have not been loaded by the `getAll()` method. Fix the toString) method so that it only accesses data that is guaranteed to be present.

If you really need to access some association once the session has been closed, then make sure this association has been loaded, either by the query, or by calling `Hibernate.initialize(classAInstance.getAssociationThatMustBeLoaded())`.

Comment: I updated my message. What is wrong with my `toString()` implementation?

Comment: Re-read my answer. The toString() of ClassA calls tries to print the contents of the set of ClassB instances it contains. So Hibernate tries to load this set. But the session is closed. So you get this exception. Don't print the set of ClassB from ClasA's toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in ClassB, but the root of this problem is in `ClassA.getClassB()`. I changed fetch strategy from lazy to eager and everything started to work perfectly as I expected:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "classA_id")
public Set<ClassB> getClassB() {
    return classB;
}
```